# how to connect Java JDBC database with MySQL DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource, minecraft

I am currently programming a Minecraft Spigot plugin and would like to use a MySQL database for it. Since a connection with a DataSource seems to be the preferred method, I would like to try to connect to my database with it. I have looked at some tutorials and read some articles about it, but they were either not understandable enough for me personally or they didn't work (anymore). Therefore I wanted to ask in this forum if someone is willing to show me step by step how to connect to a MySQL database with a DataSource and how to work with it? I would be very grateful.
Kind regards!
StraussFalke

Comment: There is a series of tutorials (recommended by @SchnellfeuerXD - I have not tried them myself): [Advanced Spigot Coding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Od-hGwKcTmg).

Comment: Otherwise, you can [edit] your question to show us what you have tried and describe where _specifically_ you are stuck. Also, don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] if you have not already done so.